# jquery autocomplete not working on non-english alphabet

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

i use jquery ui autocomplete widget one of my project. it works very well on latin alphabet but on russiın or Armenian alphabet is not working.

database returns valid list according to my search string. but combo list is not opening..

is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Some code will be help, also do you get any error ? Do you debug on browser to see whats happens ? Can you give here at least the letters that you try and did not get anything ?